# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. If $K \subset X$ is compact, then it is closed

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a question about the following proof by contradiction.

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. If $K \subset X$ is compact, then it is closed.
>
> Proof. We show if $K$ is not closed, then it is not compact. If $K$ is not closed, then there is $p \in \overline{K} \setminus K$. From $p \in \overline{K}$, we know for every $r>0$, $B_{r}(p) \cap K \ne \emptyset$. Consider for $n \in \mathbb{N}$
>
> \begin{align*}
> U_{n} = (\overline{B}_{\frac{1}{n}}(p))'
> \end{align*}
>
> then 
>   \begin{align*}
> \bigcup U_{n} = \bigg(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{B}_{\frac{1}{n}}(p)\bigg)
> \end{align*}
>
> So
>
> \begin{align*}
> \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_{n} = X \setminus \{p\} \supset K
> \end{align*}
>
> and we have an open cover $(U_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $K$.
>
> If $K$ were compact, we would have a finite subcover $(U_{n})_{n \in F}$, $|F| < \infty$, and we would have $N = \max \{n: n \in F \}$ with $U_{N} = \bigcup_{n \in F} U_{n}$
>
> We see 
>   \begin{align*}
> B_{\frac{1}{N}}(p) &\subset \overline{B}_{\frac{1}{N}}(p) =(U_{N})'
> \end{align*}
>
> This gives us a contradiction between subcover property 
>   \begin{align*}
> K \subset U_{N}
> \end{align*}

I was wondering if the contradiction has to do with $B_{r}(p) \cap K \ne \emptyset$ since there exists at least one element of $K$ in $B_{r}(p)$, but every element in $B_{\frac{1}{N}}(p)$ is an element of $(U_{N})'$. Then this implies that an element of $K$ is in $(U_{N})'$, which is the contradiction?

Comment: In $(U_N)'$, what does the $'$ stand for?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: it stands for the complement of the set

Comment: what is K bar (second line of the proof)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contradiction lies in that there is some $x \in K \cap B_{\frac1N}(p)$ as $p \in \overline{K}$. This $x$ does not lie in $U_N$ by definition, so $K \subseteq U_N$ does not hold, as $x \in K$ but $x \notin U_N$.

The proof could also be done following the general topology fact that $X$ is Hausdorff: let $p \notin K$. Then for each $x \in K$ we pick $r_x >0$ such that

$$B(x,r_x) \cap B(p, r_x) = \emptyset$$ (e.g. $r_x = \frac{d(x,p)}{2} >0$ will work)

And the $\{B(x,r_x): x \in K\}$ cover $K$, so finitely many do by compactness, say
all balls $B(x,r_x)$ for $x \in F \subseteq K$, where $F$ is finite.
Then check that $B(p, r) \cap K = \emptyset$ for $r=\min(r_x: x \in F\} >0$ (as we take a minimum of finitely many radii), and so $p \notin \overline{K}$.

Or use sequential compactness instead, if you've covered that...